# Personal Paypal account - notification to do processing?

Tags: paypal

PayPal only sends IPN for accounts that are either premier or business. The merchant account that my client has is only a **Personal** PayPal account, and he has no intention to upgrade it.

Is there any way that PayPal can send notifications to my web application upon receiving payment, so that I may process the payments? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can I ask why they would not want to make it a business account? there are no costs associated here...

Comment: lol not exactly sure of the reason, they seems to think they are required to be a business entity before choosing the business acc. Now I am trying to convince them to take up a premier account, no replies on that yet. So I just wanted to prepare a backup solution. ^^

Comment: I don't believe there are any specific requirements to be a registered business entity, as if someone were selling clothes from their living room, it would be a business, self employed but could perhaps be not a registered business. Free-Lance workers for example, would have the same issues. You can partake in business activity without being a registerd business with Company House (here in the UK)